# Missing framework when running Titanium iOS module in the test harness

Tags: ios, frameworks, module, titanium

I have the [example code](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/iOS+Module+Development+Guide) for building iOS modules working - it draws a red square. I have added a framework to my module in XCode and build.py still succeeds. But, when I run the module test harness with 'titanium run' build fails and the log file shows the message "ld: framework not found MyFramework"

How could the module build successfully but not work in the module test harness and how can I make it work both places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frameworks are linked when the module test harness runs so build.py can succeed regardless of the framework situation.

The problem here was that I needed to specify the local folder where MyFramework was sitting like this:

OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -F"${HOME}/Documents/test/module/" -framework MyFramework